# How can I check if a tandem 20amp breaker is dead on one side

Tags: bathroom, circuit-breaker, gfci

During a small garage project I was adding 2 more electrical outlets. A would be adding a tandem breaker. While doing so I was drilling thru the header to run new wire for new outlets and struck a live wire that controls the fix outlets going to my bathrooms. After realizing my mistake the hard way I cut out the bad section of wire and ran a junction box in the attic, then continued with project. Had power for several weeks now I do t have any to the bathrooms but do to the new outlets in the garage. Thing it was a bad outlet I replaced with a new one but still do t have any power. What am I missing for a it possible that one side of the tandem breaker has gone bad that fast.

Comment: do you have a basic tool to detect power ? Do you have any GFCI

Comment: Might be time to call a pro, sounds like the repair wasn't very effective. That can start a fire inside the walls, which is extremely hard to put out or even detect until it's fully engaged.  So it's vital it is done right.

Comment: Swap hot wires on the tandem and see what changes if anything.  This will also clear any "loose wire" failures.

Answer (score 1):

I would check at the box where you spliced the damaged wire is the power there?

I have had apprentices have a similar issue with wire nuts and the splice did not make an electrical connection, it could be on the hot or neutral and with no complete circuit the receptacles or fixtures do not work.

Another place to check is at the panel the breaker and neutral. either connection could have been damaged by the high current caused by drilling into the conductors.

Tracing the conductors back there could be receptacles or other points where splices could have failed after the short from the drill but working back from the repair to the panel checking both the current carrying conductor or the neutral (black- white most often) there will be a bad connection.